# Is inotify_init contained in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I am quite sure the answer is yes... but I would like to ensure.

My goal is to compile Samba 4.2.0 on a D-Link DNS-323, but my last error is:

```
default/source3/smbd/notify_inotify_75.o: In function `inotify_setup':
notify_inotify.c:(.text+0x984): undefined reference to `inotify_init'
default/source3/smbd/notify_inotify_75.o: In function `watch_destructor':
notify_inotify.c:(.text+0xe34): undefined reference to `inotify_rm_watch'
default/source3/smbd/notify_inotify_75.o: In function `inotify_watch':
notify_inotify.c:(.text+0xfd4): undefined reference to `inotify_add_watch'
notify_inotify.c:(.text+0x1150): undefined reference to `inotify_rm_watch'
notify_inotify.c:(.text+0x11ec): undefined reference to `inotify_rm_watch'
```

So, I think my only hope would be to compile a newer Kernel. Do I am right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: `inotify_init`, `inotify_add_watch` and others are **user space** functions provided by libc in form of **syscalls**. There is no such functions in the Linux **kernel**. It seems you want to compile a user-space applications in the kernel environment. This will never work.

Comment: @stark Finally, I simply override the OS for Debian and now I didn't had to compile stuff. So, unfortunately, I can't test this anymore. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Not 100% sure to have understand what you said, by read my previous comments and you'll see I can't test anymore. Thank you for you help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the hardware I was working now as been wipe with another OS.